# Modifications in files appeared again after Tortoise Git reverting

Tags: git, tortoisegit

Im using TortoiseGit and in some cases I got this error.

1. I have modified files, which I haven't changed by myself.
2. I'm reverting them and everything looks good. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1pAH.png)
3. But when I hit F5 and refresh window, again I see those changes.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyDYJ.png)

So I couldnt do anything with this folder. First I've thought of some problems with Line Ending but in list there are binary files, so thats could be the reason. Any advice?

[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like an app outside of git is changing those files.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I've tried to do after fresh system loading, same thing. Looks like its git itself changing those files.

Comment: Git doesn't/won't change files. Do you have a git hook installed?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found the source of the problem, but after I've installed fresh version of TortoiseGit and re-downloaded sources - problem has gone and now everything works as it should.